# Небинарное дерево на c++

Tags: c++, дерево

Мне нужно написать небинарное дерево на c++ с использованием `map<string, Node>`, где `string` характеризует узел, `Node` хранит список детей. Мне не совсем понятно как реализовать начальную структуру класса с использованием `map`. Для дерева нужно реализовать

```
addRoot(const std::string& rootName)
addNode(const std::string& parent, const std::string& nodeName)
operator<<
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного теории:

Можно так вкратце описать карту:  всегда хранит сочетание ключ - значение. Ключ уникален. Значение - не обязательно. Ключом может выступать любой тип или объект. Значением тоже. Задача описана не очень хорошо, но могу предположить, что вам подойдет такой пример:

```
for (auto i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
map[i] = new Object(*argv);
}
```

Только в вашем случае i - строка

Answer (score 0):

Ну в принципе ничего сложного. Только размышлять надо немного в другую сторону. `map<>` - просто контейнер, который физически хранит ваши узлы. Считайте, что он к дереву не имеет никакого отношения.
У каждого узла есть идентификатор (у вас это `string`), и список потомков.  Список потомков можно реализовать например через `set<string>` или `unordered_set<string>` в котором будут идентификаторы узлов-потомков.
Для ускорения операций удаления и обхода дерева, можно дополнительно хранить в узле идентификатор родителя.
Можно создать класс для узла, а можно и не делать. `map<>` хранит пары, вот узлом и будет пара `pair< string, unordered_set<string> >`. Или структура, по факту реализующая ту же пару:

```
struct TreeNode
{  
   string id;
   unordered_set<string> Children;
   TreeNode(string& str) : id(str) {}
};

// создание элемента
TreeNode n("001");
// добавление элемента в хранилище
map[n.id] = n; // через копирование
```

Добавление к родителям надеюсь сами напишете.
Если в узле реализовать конструктор перемещения, то объекты и копироваться не будут, а будут перемещаться в/из словаря.
В `pair<>` перемещения уже сделаны.